# Angular 10 two way Data Binding in Reactive form using ngif for form validation

Tags: angular-ng-if, angular10, two-way-binding

I am using two way data binding in reactive form but I think it is not working properly because in ngif condition only if condition is working not else condition.
[In this image I want that if admin enter anything else than 'teacher' in Designation input then subject will be disable otherwise it should be enable for 'teacher'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/APMgR.png)

Here is code

```
<td><div class="form-group mb-2">
        <label for="email" class=" mx-sm-3">Designation</label>
        <input type="text" formControlName="Designation"  class="form-control"  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.Designation.errors }" #Designation/>
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.Designation.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                      <div *ngIf="f.Designation.errors.required">Designation is required</div>
    </div>
      </div>
    </td>
```

ngif condition

```
<ng-template
  *ngIf="techer();then ifShow; else ifNotShow">
</ng-template>

<ng-template #ifShow>

  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="sel1" class="mx-sm-3"> Subjects: </label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="Subjects" id="sel1"  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.Subjects.errors }" >
      <option *ngFor="let account of subjects" [value]="account.Sub_Title">{{ account.Sub_Title }}</option>
    </select>
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.Subjects.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.Subjects.errors.required">Subject is required</div>
  </div>
  </div>
</ng-template>

<ng-template #ifNotShow>

  <div class="form-group mb-2">
    <label for="sel1" class="mx-sm-3"> Subjects: </label>
    <select class="form-control" formControlName="Subjects" id="sel1"  [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.Subjects.errors }" [attr.disabled]="true">
      <option *ngFor="let account of subjects" [value]="account.Sub_Title">{{ account.Sub_Title }}</option>
    </select>
      <div *ngIf="submitted && f.Subjects.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
      <div *ngIf="f.Subjects.errors.required">Subject is required</div>
  </div>
  </div>

</ng-template>
```

in component.ts file

```
techer(){

    if(this.form.get('Designation').value === 'Teacher || teacher'){
      return !this.Tr; //Tr is boolean value which initially false
    }
    else{
      return this.Tr;
    }
  }
```

Kindly help me to sourt out the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your if/else statement is not correct, you can't use an OR || operator in a string like that. Your if else statement will now always fail on the first check.

try to use this instead:

```
if (this.form.get('Designation').value.toLowerCase() === 'teacher') {

}
```